# Nivo Slider doesn't work at all

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

I've tried to put a nivo-slider [on my website's home page](http://www.medica.be).
For some reason, it doesn't show at all. I can't manage to figure out why it doesn't...

**UPDATE: it now shows only a static image :S (I placed the jquery library before the actual script**

I put this in my header: (header is located in the layout.php file in directory /site)

```
<!--NIVO SLIDER-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="site/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="site/nivo-slider/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="site/nivo-slider/themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

This is what I put in index.php (file located in the main directory):

```
<? require('site/layout.php');

function banner($DB) {
?>
    <div class='slider-wrapper'>
        <div id='slider' class='nivoSlider theme-default'>
            <img src='site/nivo-slider/slide1.jpg' alt='' />
            <a href='http://dev7studios.com'><img src='site/nivo-slider/slide2.jpg' alt='' title='#htmlcaption' /></a>
            <img src='site/nivo-slider/slide3.jpg' alt='' title='This is an example of a caption' />
            <img src='site/nivo-slider/slide4.jpg' alt='' />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='htmlcaption' class='nivo-html-caption'>
        <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href='#'>a link</a>.
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
    </script>
<? 
}
```

After this block of code, two other functions are called:
function body_text_left($DB) & function body_text_right($DB)
(the left and right side of the page, BELOW the nivo-slider)

All the nivo-slider files are located in this direcory: /site/nivo-slider

It's weird, because when I look at the source code, everything is there. All links will load when I click on them.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's conflicting with another script

Comment: Ok I got some improvement! I placed the jquery library BEFORE the actual script. It now shows an image... But just a still, static image :(

Comment: Take a look at jquery no conflict

Comment: I see this error in console: RangeError: invalid array length var nivoslider = new NivoSlider(this, options);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, repair this:

```
<? require('site/layout.php');

function banner($DB) {
?>
```

into:

```
<?php require('site/layout.php');

echo 'function banner($DB) {';
?>
```

You have `prototype.js` in your script. Put script load of prototype after nivo slider or turn off to check problem.

On last line in `index.php` try instead:

```
<? 
}
```

as:

```
<?php 
echo '}';
?>
```

Try put `jquery.js` at bottom of code.

Comment: I didn't need to echo the function, that corrupts the code! Although, thanks a lot for mentionning prototype.js! That's the culprit! Case closed ;)

Comment: Wohooo, i didn't know that I'm correct! Thank you! One point to you, too!